# Using an if statement to alter a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I've got a loop. It echoes each item in an array. However, I want to wrap one of the items with some custom content. At the moment, I can do that, but it repeats it unnecessarily. Here is my loop:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

foreach ($arr as $key) {
    if ($key == 5) {
        echo 'wrap';
        echo $key;
        echo 'wrap';
    }
        echo $key;
}
```

Which produces:

```
1
2
3
4
WRAP
5
WRAP
5 <--- remove
6
```

As you can see, the `$key` 5 is being duplicated. I just need to wrap it once when it's called. Is there a way to only echo `5` once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's currently written, the `echo` statement after your `if` block will get executed on each loop iteration. You only want that to happen when the value of `$key` is ***not*** `5`. So use the `else` block:

```
foreach ($arr as $key) {
    if ($key == 5) {
        echo 'wrap';
        echo $key;
        echo 'wrap';
    } else {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. What would happen if I wanted to wrap both `4` and `5` in the same thing? I have this, but it wraps both individually: `($key == 3 || $key == 4)`. I'm trying to get `wrap 3 4 wrap`

Comment: @tmyie: Then it will be wrapped if `$key` equals `3` **OR** `4`. See demo: https://eval.in/126449

Comment: Sorry, I meant so I get this result: `wrap 3 4 wrap` (so both numbers are wrapped in the same thing)

Comment: @tmyie: What do you need this for?

Comment: I'm trying to stop repeated HTML content (and learning in the process). I've fixed it now, thanks to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

foreach ($arr as $key) {
    if ($key == 5) {
        echo 'wrap';
        echo $key;
        echo 'wrap';
    } else {
        echo $key;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, simple, just add an 'else' statement:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

foreach ($arr as $key) {
    if ($key == 5) {
        echo 'wrap';
        echo $key;
        echo 'wrap';
    } else {
        echo $key;
    }    
}
```